# Nurse rostering using ortools constraint solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, or-tools

I went through [tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling) and I seem to understand most of the code. My problem is that they choose solutions only based on hard constraints. Most of papers also use soft constraints and every constraint has it's coeficient. Sum of all constraints each multiplied by their coeficient produces a cost of the roster, so the goal is to minimize this value. My question is, how can I add this to the code?

```
# Create the decision builder.
db = solver.Phase(shifts_flat, solver.CHOOSE_FIRST_UNBOUND,
                solver.ASSIGN_MIN_VALUE)

# Create the solution collector.
solution = solver.Assignment()
solution.Add(shifts_flat)
collector = solver.AllSolutionCollector(solution)
solver.Solve(db, [collector])
```

I'm not sure what the decision builder does (or it's parameters), nor `solver.Assignment()`, nor `solver.AllSolutionCollector(solution)`.

Only thing I found is [this](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt_cp#objective), but I'm not sure how to use it. (maybe call `solver.Minimize(cost, ?)` instead of assignment?)

Comment: or-tools is pretty huge and the documentation is quite sparse. From what i have gathered (take it with a grain of salt): 1: There are at least 3 very different core decision-procedures: CP-Solver, SAT-based CP-Solver and LP/01-MIP/MIP Solvers (with different backends; e.g. or-tools Bop vs. Cbc). 2: Your `this` link` is part of the MIP-interface and you cannot use it. There is no automatic transform and MIPs are harder to post. 3: CP-Solver is somewhat deprecated and replaced by SAT-based solver (some examples transformed; but the docs are somewhat outdated). For SAT-based CP, go through...

Comment: [code_samples_sat.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/code_samples_sat.py) and the API [cp_model.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py). A newer SAT-CP-based nurse-rostering is in [nurses_sat](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/nurses_sat.py). From those you can see that there is still a `model.Minimize(obj_var)`, but it looks rather simplified (no factors?). You probably need to **reify** all your constraints manually (with a potential penalty) and then call `minimize` on those reified terms

Comment: You might get more help in the official [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/or-tools-discuss). Reading a bit through it + the issue-tracker will give you some information (as for example the: we now use SAT-based CP all the time; but not all examples are transformed; look for the `_sat` suffix).

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/index.md. I am compiling a list of modeling constructs.

Comment: One thing is not clear to me. Why can't I use MIP solver? I think it's the right approach. I basically want to minimize cost by setting some integer (boolean) variables. If I understand this correctly, SAT solver finds a solution using only hard constraints. (or am I wrong?)

Comment: You are wrong. The SAT solver supports half-reified constraint: boolean => constraint. This combined with adding this booleans to the objective allows implementing soft constraints. The main difference between the SAT solver and a MIP solver is the expressive power of the Solver. MIP solvers supports linear inequalities. Our CP-SAT solvers supports scheduling, and complex integer constraints: See the Add methods on the CpModel part: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/98f243b438537c46b080d7d16f89fdb21c3b1170/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py#L500

Comment: Please note that if the model is naturally expressed as a linear problem on boolean variable, it is likely MIP solvers will outperform the CP-SAT solver.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

The data defines employee requests:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py#L219

The model directly creates one bool var for each tuple (employee, day, shift).

Thus adding that to the objective is straightforward:

```
# Employee requests
for e, s, d, w in requests:
    obj_bool_vars.append(work[e, s, d])
    obj_bool_coeffs.append(w)
```

This is used in the minimize code:

```
# Objective
model.Minimize(
    sum(obj_bool_vars[i] * obj_bool_coeffs[i]
        for i in range(len(obj_bool_vars))) + sum(
            obj_int_vars[i] * obj_int_coeffs[i]
            for i in range(len(obj_int_vars))))
```